# Sort list/kanban view by integer formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, list-view, kanban

I have a requirement in which I will need to sort a list/kanban view by an integer formula field.

Is this possible? I've checked the documentantion and found nothing related to this topic.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this. Here is my Account List View sorted by Days Old (a Number formula field):

[image]